# Rescale PCB in Altium (Inches to mm)

Tags: pcb, altium

So I accidentally made my PCB using inches instead of mm so the dimensions are now completely wrong. Is there a quick way to rescale the board or do I have to start again? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Press Q to change dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:
making a board outline on a blank mechanical layer with the place line tool.

make sure all of the edges are connected together.

select one edge so it is highlighted,
press tab key, this should select the entire perimeter
(if not, you have discontinuities at the some of the endpoints)

When you get the entire perimeter to highlight go to menu Design->Boad Shape->Define Board Shape From Selected objects (or shortcut-ly: D S D keys)

If this fails you will get a message "Could not find board outline..."
You can press yes and it may give you the correct outline but it is better to reexamine the outline construct, fix the discontinuity and try again. The message will give you an indication via grid coordinates where your discontinuity is.

You should then have a PCB area the size of your board-outline-construct on your board outline mechanical layer.

When you are done you can delete the mechanical layer you used to make the board edge, or, alternatively, keep it for your Gerber outputs.  This comes in handy for the Fabricator.